# If cell = closed project, cut cell and past into "Projects closed" worksheet on next available row

Tags: excel, vba

Currently working on a spread sheet to track work progress. row "C" has a drop down from cells C12:C3000, if this is selected to "Project closed" I need to row to be cut and paste to the worksheet "Project closed" with no empty row left once the row is cut.

I have come across this VBA code and adapted it to my own use. but to no avail.

```
Sub cut_paste()
    Dim i As Variant
    Dim endrow As Integer
    Dim ASR As Worksheet, LS As Worksheet

    Set ASR = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("In Progress")
    Set LS = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Project Closed")

    endrow = ASR.Range("A" & ASR.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 3 To endrow
        If ASR.Cells(i, "C").Value = "Project Closed" Then
           ASR.Cells(i, "C").EntireRow.cut Destination:=LS.Range("A" & LS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to cut rows, and don't want an empty row left, try this instead:

```
For i = endrow To 3 Step -1
    If ASR.Cells(i, "C").Value = "Project Closed" Then
           ASR.Cells(i, "C").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=LS.Range("A" & LS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
           ASR.Cells(i, "C").EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next
```

This should go through the ASR sheet, copy any matches, then remove that row and continue onwards.

Comment: Fantastic, this worked a dream. Thank you for the help Batman.

Comment: @DarrenHadland - Just to note too - if you're ever going through a sheet and deleting rows, it's always best to start at the end and step backwards.  Otherwise, if you go forwards, when you delete a row, the next `i` would be the **next** row...since the rows move up when you delete, it'll effectively skip a row.  ...does that make sense? That's why I did `for i = endRow to 3 Step -1`, instead of `for i = 3 to endRow`.